# Cannot run mysql count (*)

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to run this query

```
SELECT a.id, count (*) as MovieCount
    FROM actors a
    JOIN roles r ON a.id = r.actor_id 
GROUP BY a.id
```

but it underlines my * in red and says Error 1064. What could be wrong about the star in parentheses?

Comment: Space between count and (*)

Comment: Yep, it worked. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The problem (as explained in a comment and deleted answer) is the space after `count`.

However, you should be aware that you can significantly simplify the query by removing the `join`:

```
SELECT r.actor_id, count(*) as MovieCount
FROM roles r
GROUP BY r.actor_id
```

Comment: I am wonder why you can see the deleted answer? Is it due to your high reputation?

Comment: Nice observation :)

Comment: @lucumt . . . Quite possibly.  I hadn't thought about it, but I can vote to undelete answers -- I think they need more than one undelete vote, though.